# Form with throbber not responding to validate or submit methods

Tags: forms, ajax

I have the following form built with Form API. Its method is GET. I try to validate or submit, but it does not work. I have checked the method names, etc., and are correct, in fact I see an "attempt" of validation in some cases. I guess that there is something weird for the way I use the select autofilling field. It is a "car models" select whose values are filled by selection of "car brand" select, and I think that the code somehow interferes with the normal use of Form API.

```
function mymodule_search_form(){
    $brands = get_brands();
    $brand = get_default_brand();

    $form['product'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Product'),
      '#autocomplete_path' => 'product-busq/productos/all',
      '#attributes' => array("placeholder" => t('Product'), ) // 'class' => array('auto_submit')
     );

     $form['brand'] = array(
       '#type' => 'select',
       '#title' => t('Brand'),
       '#options' => $brands,
       '#default_value' => $brand,
       '#ajax' => array(
           'callback' => 'mymodule_models_update',
           'wrapper' => 'models_wrapper',
           'progress' => array(
           'message' => '',
           'type' => 'throbber',
          ),
         ),
        );

    $form['model'] = array(

      '#type' => "select",
      '#title' => t('Model'),
      '#required' => FALSE,
      '#multiple' => YES,
      '#attributes' => array("placeholder" => t('Model'), ), // 'class' => array('auto_submit')

       '#prefix' => '<div id="models_wrapper">',
       '#suffix' => '</div>',
       '#disabled' => TRUE,
      );

  $form['submit'] = array(
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#value' => t('Submit'),
      '#name' => ""
 );

   $form["#action"] = $base_url . "/" . $language->language . "/" .   drupal_get_path_alias("node/3");
  $form["#method"] = "get";

  return $form;
} // function
```

And now the autofilling function which may be causing the problems, especially the last sentence. The code is copied from a tutorial somewhere:

```
function mymodule_models_update($form, &$form_state) {
   unset($form_state['input']['model'], $form_state['values']['model']);
   $brand = $form_state['values']['brand'];
   $brand_desc = "";
   $results = db_query("SELECT description FROM {taxonomy_term_data} tax WHERE tax.tid = :tid", array(":tid" => $brand));
    foreach($results as $row) $brand_desc = $row->description;

    if($brand_desc != "") $form['model']['#options'] =      _hook_list_models($brand_desc);
    unset($form['model']["#attributes"]['disabled']);
   $form['model']['#disabled'] = FALSE;
   $form["model"]["#attributes"]["id"] = "edit-model";
   return form_builder($form['#id'], $form['model'], $form_state);
 } // function
```

Comment: Please do not define any function with `hook_` prefix. It is reserved for implementing hook API.

Comment: You should use `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` instead of calling `form_builder()` to rebuild the form. In the ajax callback, you should only return the dynamic part only. In your case, it is `return $form['model'];`

Comment: In fact it is the name of the module, maybe I had better used *mymodule_* to make it clear.

Comment: hook_models is the module name? It is not a good idea. LOL

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, but I don't catch the funny thing of it, though I suspect something. Uhm... BTW, your solution works, but only if the method is POST instead of GET. Strange.

Comment: `hook_` prefix is really a bad idea. I laugh because it will make other Drupal developer confused. And it may cause function name conflict in future as well.

Comment: I never make ajax form with GET method. So I can't tell you why and how to fix it if you want GET method.

Comment: I found explanation from official [doc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7.x). **"Note that 'get' method forms do not use form ids so are always considered to be submitted, which can have unexpected effects."**

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I will revert to POST, and using your correction, it works perfectly. Thank you very much. I update the hook by mymodule to avoid confusion. Thanks again.

Comment: I have made my comment as answer here. Hope it can help others. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Drupal official documentation on [`drupal_build_form`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7.x).

> **method:** The HTTP form method to use for finding the input for this form. May be 'post' or 'get'. Defaults to 'post'. Note that 'get' method forms do not use form ids so are always considered to be submitted, which can have unexpected effects. The 'get' method should only be used on forms that do not change data, as that is exclusively the domain of 'post.'

I would recommend you using POST method rather then GET method, so please remove the line `$form["#method"] = "get";`

Also, you should rewrite your ajax callback.

```php
function hook_models_update($form, &$form_state) {
   unset($form_state['input']['model'], $form_state['values']['model']);
   $brand = $form_state['values']['brand'];
   $brand_desc = "";
   $results = db_query("SELECT description FROM {taxonomy_term_data} tax WHERE tax.tid = :tid", array(":tid" => $brand));
    foreach($results as $row) $brand_desc = $row->description;

    if($brand_desc != "") $form['model']['#options'] =      _hook_list_models($brand_desc);
    unset($form['model']["#attributes"]['disabled']);
   $form['model']['#disabled'] = FALSE;
   $form["model"]["#attributes"]["id"] = "edit-model";

   $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
   return $form['model'];
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

If you can, I would suggest you rename your function or module name to avoid using `hook_` prefix. It would cause unexpected function name conflict in future, because `hook_` prefix is reserved for building hook API in Drupal.